# Gitlab scan worktree on push and zip files bigger than 20MB

Tags: gitlab

We have some raw data files that get updated quite frequently in our repository which are used during the build process of our app. I usually zip these files because they are x times smaller when zipped so I'd like to automate this process and let my repository to do this job for me. The repo performance is also much faster when all datafiles are zipped due to the reduced filesize.

Is there any possibility in Gitlab to scan the received worktree when pushed for files bigger than 20MB and zip those files before finishing the push?

Or is there anything similar that can be done to achieve a similar goal?